# Circle selection in an Integer[][] matrix - Java

Tags: java, algorithm, math, image-processing

I have a matrix with n columns, n rows and every element is initialized with 0.

I want to select the largest circle in that matrix, and set the values to 1.

```
000010000
000111000
000111000
001111100
011111110     The drawing isnt't very artistic (or correct)...  
001111100        matrix: 9*9
000111000        largest circle
000111000
000010000
```

Can you help me with the java algorithm ?

Language: Java

Thank you,
Horatiu

Comment: I'm just wondering, is this homework?

Comment: This guy is asking people to give him an algorithm? What the hell???

Comment: On this site you will get answers if you post code. You will not find people who write your code for you. Come up with your own ideas, try them, post here what went wrong, and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: I use this for a red eye removal tool; If I have an ideea how to do it I would of done it by now; I said the drawing isn't so artistic, but a circle is what I want; And yes, I want the algorithm - maybe even a link or anything helpful. Any more questions ?

Comment: I don't think this should be closed as "Not a real question", as it is perfectly clear what is being asked here... just that the asker has not shown his personal efforts at solving the problem. So either downvote/don't answer/ask him to show his work or point him to the answer, but don't vote to close (unless of course it is a dupe, in  which case, vote away!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a naive algorithm. It fills in each point to a 0 or 1 depending upon whether it lies inside or outside the circle.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] matrix = new int[9][];
    double midPoint = (matrix.length-1)/2.0;
    for (int col = 0; col < matrix.length; col++)
    {
        int[] row = new int[matrix.length];
        double yy = col-midPoint;
        for (int x=0; x<row.length; x++)
        {
           double xx = x-midPoint;
           if (Math.sqrt(xx*xx+yy*yy)<=midPoint)
             row[x] = 1;
           System.out.print(row[x]);
        }
        matrix[col] = row;
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

The most efficient way to find proper pixels of a circle boundary is the Bresenhamn's algorithm or Mid Point Circle Algorithm; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm#Optimization

this is how I change that to fit yours:

```
public class Circle {
    private char[][] px;
    private char cEmpty='.';
    private char cFilled='#';
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Circle(15);
    }
    public Circle(int size)
    {
        px=new char[size][size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
                px[i][j]=cEmpty;
        calc(size/2,size/2,size/2-1);
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
                System.out.print(px[i][j]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void calc(int cx, int cy, int radius)
    {
      int error = -radius;
      int x = radius;
      int y = 0;
      while (x >= y)
      {
        plot8points(cx, cy, x, y);   
        error += y;
        ++y;
        error += y;
        if (error >= 0)
        {
          --x;
          error -= x;
          error -= x;
        }
      }
    }

    void plot8points(int cx, int cy, int x, int y)
    {
      plot4points(cx, cy, x, y);
      if (x != y) plot4points(cx, cy, y, x);
    }
    void plot4points(int cx, int cy, int x, int y)
    {
      setPixel(cx + x, cy + y);
      if (x != 0) setPixel(cx - x, cy + y);
      if (y != 0) setPixel(cx + x, cy - y);
      if (x != 0 && y != 0) setPixel(cx - x, cy - y);
    }
    void setPixel(int x, int y){
        px[x][y]=cFilled;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. But I have chosen mdma's implementation because his circle is filled.